# Error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) " in a variadic function

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I have this method which supposed to take variable number of String arguments and put them in an NSMutableArray:

```
    - (id)testArray: (NSString*) question, ... {

        NSMutableArray* questionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:question, nil];
        id eachObject;
        [_questionsArray addObject:question];
        va_list list;
        va_list (list, question);
        while ((eachObject = va_arg(args, id)) != nil) {
              [_questionsArray addObject:eachObject];
        }
        va_end(args);
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to replace `va_list(list, question);` with `va_start(list, question)` in addition to what's stated in the answer below.

Comment: You are also putting `question` in the array twice.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your instructions and the one below. It finally worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not run as written, but most likely the source of your bad access error is that you're not nil terminating your argument list when calling the function.

i.e.

```
[self testArray:@"abc123", @"def456", nil];
```

https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html